# How to make clickable widget behind stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have two `scaffold` widget in the stack for some purposes .. And every `scaffold` has its own contents .
the second scaffold has transparent background colors so the first scaffold is visible.

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: myBody(),
      ),
    ),
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ...,
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

the `GestureDetector` in first `Scaffold`does not work and that's because of the Scaffold stack

Note : I can't wrap the second `Scaffold` with `IgnorePointer` because it has clickable ListView.bulder which gonna be ignoring any pointer too

How could I solve this ×_O

Answer (score 1):

You can get callback method from second scaffold list item tap. And create a function on level that will be provided on first scaffold  `GestureDetector`.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  Widget myBody() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.3),
    );
  }

  void topLevelGesture() {
    debugPrint("got hit on GestureDetector");
  }

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        children: [
          Scaffold(
            body: GestureDetector(
              onTap: topLevelGesture,
              child: myBody(),
            ),
          ),
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("item $index"),
                onTap: () {
                  topLevelGesture();
                  print("tapped $index");
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by taking the position `Offset` and `Size` of the widget in the first item of the stack, then positioning it in the custom clickable widget according to the `Offset` and `Size` of the first widget using `RenderBox` object.

```dart
body: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  children: [
    PartBehindView(), // 1
    PartFrontView(), // 2
    _customClickableWidget(context),
  ],
),
```

In the first view widget, I used `GlobalObjectKey` of a widget, then in the custom clickable widget, I called the same `GlobalObjectKey` to get the `Offset` and `Size`. Then apply it to the custom clickable widget.

For me this works well, but maybe there is another better way.

Answer (score -1):

You can set Gesture as outside of the stack and with this inner list click also works but when you put the first Scaffold body as a clickable it's not working because the second Scaffold overlay that.

```
GestureDetector(
         onTap(){}
         child:Stack(
    children[
       Scaffold(
       body:   myBody()
        
         )
      Scaffold(
       backGroundColor: Colors.transparent
       body: ListView.bulder(){....}
       )
     ]
    ))
```

Comment: @Jack did you try this I have try and it's working.

Comment: thanks Jasmin but it does not work for me

Answer (score -1):

You need to add clickable widget at the end in your stack widget as below:

```
   Stack(
    children[
      firstWidget(),
      GestureDetector(
      onTap(){},
      child:  secondWidget()
      )
      
   ]
   )
```

Comment: thanks but How this will be a solution ?  it still prevent any pointer response in the first element on the stack !

Answer (score -1):

Just use `IgnorePointer` like this for `secondWidget()`, and `firstWidget()` can clickable.

```
    Stack(
        children[
          firstWidget(),
          IgnorePointer(
            child: secondWidget(),
          ),
        ]
    )
```